# MySQL primary key column not visible in QGIS 2.6

Tags: qgis, mysql

I've tried adding a vector from Mysql table (Mysql 5.1, MyISAM) to QGIS 2.6.
All columns are visible except Primary key column(s).

Could anyone confirm this behaviour? Could we consider it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that GDAL is taking your primary key column and uses it as a FID which is the internal Feature ID. That is not meant to be published as a normal attribute. See the following example. The table in the Spatialite has a column OGC_FID which is selected to be used as FID and it does not appear in the attributes of the feature. The value of the OGC_FID field is used in `OGRFeature(points):1`

```
ogrinfo OSM.sqlite points
INFO: Open of `OSM.sqlite'
      using driver `SQLite' successful.

Layer name: points
Geometry: Point
Feature Count: 314281
Extent: (19.065536, 59.457619) - (31.464966, 70.089821)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
FID Column = OGC_FID              <= this line shows where the FID is taken
Geometry Column = GEOMETRY
osm_id: String (0.0)
name: String (0.0)
barrier: String (0.0)
highway: String (0.0)
ref: String (0.0)
address: String (0.0)
is_in: String (0.0)
place: String (0.0)
man_made: String (0.0)
other_tags: String (0.0)

OGRFeature(points):1                <= No OGC_FID included in the attributes
  osm_id (String) = 115899
  name (String) = (null)
  barrier (String) = (null)
  highway (String) = traffic_signals
  ref (String) = (null)
  address (String) = (null)
  is_in (String) = (null)
  place (String) = (null)
  man_made (String) = (null)
  other_tags (String) = (null)
  POINT (25.7409545 66.49637)
```

There are workarounds. You must select the fid as a normal attribute and you can probably do it either in

1. Database by making a view "CREATE VIEW expose AS SELECT PK_COLUMN as PK_COLUMN, PK_COLUMN AS EXPOSED PK_COLUMN ..."
2. Read the database table through GDAL virtual vector format http://www.gdal.org/drv_vrt.html and define the PK column twice in there
3. Use GDAL/OGR SQL support. Here is an example:

> ```
> ogrinfo OSM.sqlite -sql "select ogc_fid as exposed_fid, name, geometry from points"
> INFO: Open of OSM.sqlite
> using driver SQLite successful.
> Layer name: SELECT
> Geometry: Unknown (any)
> Feature Count: 314281
> OGRFeature(SELECT):0
> exposed_fid (Integer) = 1    <= OGC_FID now listed as a normal attribute
> name (String) = (null)
> POINT (25.7409545 66.49637)
> ```